Are spectral subtypes a logarithmic scale, or a linear one?
Are spectral subclasses logarithmic? I can't seem to find any source on whether they're linear or logarithmic. For reference, by spectral subtypes I mean, for example, G2 vs G3 stars.

Strictly speaking, neither.  The types and sub-types are qualitatively defined in terms of spectral features (the presence or absence of various lines) and the relationship to photosphere temperature is a derived and secondary property.
In practice the relationship is mixed. In the graph below the logarithm of temperatures (source) are plotted against spectral type.

If there were a simple logarithmic relationship, you would expect a straight line.  That works reasonably well for the G, F and A stars, and also for the B stars (but at different parameters)  but the M and K stars have a linear interpolation (giving a curved section of the graph), and the O type stars are a little scattered too.
The evidence from these data is that the scaling of sub-types from 9-to-0 isn't done by simple mathematical scaling applied equally to all types, unlike (for example) the logarithmic magnitude or decibel scales.
